# Stream games from PC to TV (no cable) at more than 60 frames per second

Tags: streaming, steam-in-home-streaming, nvidia-geforce-experience

Is there any way to stream games from PC to TV wirelessly at 120+ FPS?

I couldn't find any on the internet.. I saw moonlight/SteamLink and even Nvidia shield are capped at 60 if I'm not mistaking.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whether or not there is a software that allows you to do this, I think you'll almost certainly run into network limitations. WiFi really doesn't have the speed/reliability for the kind of data transfer that's needed for the application you're talking about.

Comment: Also, is your TV capable of showing *true* 120hz? A most TVs use a different display type to monitors, which means that they can't truly show 120hz. You'll need to check online. Otherwise, there isn't much point in streaming 120hz in the first place :)

Answer (score -3):

Nope. Not at this moment in time.

Comment: Would you be able to expand on your answer?